# Timer not going off

Tags: c#, software-engineering

I've got a timer in my game which is supposed to set off a Boolean back to false after a certain amount of time has passed it just doesn't seem to work despite me trying to debug the issue, although setting off the timer works perfectly fine. Any help with this would be much appreciated

```
for (int i = 0; i < cameras.Count; ++i)
            {
                DetectCamera camera = cameras[i];
                Stopwatch camTimer = new Stopwatch();

                if (player.InterferenceStart && player.EMPBoundingCircle.Intersects(camera.BoundingRectangle))
                    camTimer.Start();

                if(camTimer.ElapsedMilliseconds >= 2000.0f)
                {
                    camera.CameraInRange = false;
                    camTimer.Reset();
                }
                else if (camTimer.IsRunning)
                    camera.CameraInRange = true;
            }
```

Comment: Normally in XNA you'd use `GameTime.ElapsedGameTime` in your `Update` function to provide timing (to count up some time, for a delay, you'd accumulate it in a variable).

Comment: I do not see how this is off-topic, Mr. Vote-to-close.

Comment: There's nothing game-related about it. It's a basic failure to understand C# object creation, Stopwatch is not an XNA class.

Comment: @Joe is right, this is not the right place to teach basic programming skills

Comment: (However, it is a clear question with a specific answer, so I didn't downvote it.)

Comment: I upvoted this question because it is clear, and has a concrete answer. The question could be on-topic on stackoverflow, but it is also on-topic here, as the asker is using XNA. We have the answer here, and programming topics often overlap with SO, so I don't think that we should be marking questions about people who are programming a *game* as off-topic.

Comment: There's nothing about XNA in the question. Like, there's not even any peripheral involvement of XNA APIs.

Comment: You are assuming it's about game-programming because of the presence of XNA? I don't see any reference to games in the question. It's about a timer, more precisely about the scope and lifetime of objects in C#. A simple programming beginner question.

Comment: There's not even the presence of XNA.

Comment: So basically if he had just added : "I'm having trouble timing my in-game camera cinematic movements", he wouldn't have been downvoted, because it would've been game related. C'mon guys loads of questions here are simply programming related but as it's on the topic of games (which considering his variable names, I guess this one is too) it's considered on topic here.

Comment: I probably still would've voted to close that.

Comment: Well I'm surprised I don't see more questions closed. Considering the amount of poor questions with no research effort shown at GameDev, I think you're pointing your over-zealous downvotes in the wrong direction.

Comment: I'm suprised I see so many useless questions upvoted, but high quality question not: [How can I implement a command system for a point and click style adventure game](http://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/601/how-can-i-implement-a-command-system-for-a-point-and-click-style-adventure-game) Why is that? That's very sad to me, given what gamedev actually stands for. Sorry for high jacking your question @dbomb101

Comment: I didn't realize that GameTime.ElapsedGameTime was updated every frame with a new value thought it was a total run time of the game, would of used it earlier if it weren't due to that. Also I think the question is valued on here as although it is a simple question (didn't have my thinking cap on that morning) it is still has a relation to games development as the program is a game and on top of that it would be likely to be downvoted even worse on stackoverflow than on here.

Comment: @3nixios: I think if you look at my voting record you'll find I point my overzealous downvotes _everywhere_. (Except, actually, here.)

Comment: Well the fact that dbomb101 now learned something about the GameTime construction shows that it was worth having it open in gamedev, doesn't it?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You declare camTimer inside a method, as soon as your code exits this method the timer will be stopped and garbage collected. Also Your code probably calls this method every frame, so camTimer is created newly everyframe, so the time is never more than a few miliseconds.

Both of these problems can be solved by moving the camTimer out of the method and into the class containing the method. For example:

```
public class MyClass()
{
    StopWatch camTimer;

    public MyClass(){
        camTimer = new camTimer();
    }

    public void StartTimer(){
        camTimer.Start();
    }

    public void StopTimer(){
        camTimer.Reset(); //stops and sets time at 0, alternatively use stop to not set at 0 but keep time
    }

    public void DoSomethingWithCameras(){
            ...
            ...
            if(camTimer.ElapsedMilliseconds > 2000.0f){
                ...
                camTimer.Restart(); //starts measuring from 0 again

            }
            ...
    }
}
```

Comment: Why would anyone downvote this?

Comment: I downvote answers to offtopic or duplicate questions to discourage reputation farming. I think it's entire fair to call answers in the wrong place "not useful", and therefore deserving of -1.